# Use of Update Panel of AJAX Extension Tab

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

i had binding some data to gridview in a page loadevent.....

And the gridview is in update panel..

i had included a Button in Each row of gridview using template field..

Every thing is working fine, But when i click on Button i am assigning a Row content's to a labels which is outside the update panel...

But this is not happening......

The Code Snippet inside the Button is working fine!!!!!

Because it was working good before the use of Update Panel........ Since the Whole page was Posting to a server to avoid this i used Update Panel..

But it is arrising another problem..

Can any Suggest how can i get out this kind of problem!!!!!!!!!!!

Thank in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generates a postback inside an UpdatePanel, by default, only the content within the panel is updated. That's the magic of the UpdatePanel :)

You'll need to include the labels you want to modify inside the same update panel the grid is or wrap them on a separated UpdatePanel and update it if the grid panel get updated.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx) you have a sample about how to trigger the update of a second update panel.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    protected DateTime LastUpdate
    {
        get
        {
            return (DateTime)(ViewState["LastUpdate"] ?? DateTime.Now);
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["LastUpdate"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LastUpdate.AddSeconds(5.0) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
            LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Button1);   
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>UpdatePanelUpdateMode Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1"
                               runat="server" />
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1"
                       GroupingText="UpdatePanel1"
                       runat="server">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"
                                 UpdateMode="Conditional"
                                 runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <p>
                            The content in this UpdatePanel only refreshes if five or more
                            seconds have passed since the last refresh and the button in
                            UpdatePanel2 was clicked. The time is checked
                            server-side and the UpdatePanel.Update() method is called. Last
                            updated: <strong>
                                <%= LastUpdate.ToString() %>
                            </strong>
                        </p>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2"
                       GroupingText="UpdatePanel2"
                       runat="server">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2"
                                 runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <p>
                            This UpdatePanel always refreshes if the button is clicked.
                            Last updated: <strong>
                                <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
                            </strong>
                        </p>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```